# What is the difference between find and filter in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#navs li').find('.activenav').filter('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
```

or

```
$('#navs li').filter('.activenav').find('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
```

Comment: Jquery docs are pretty good. [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for the selector match in the descendants of the source collection and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) at the same level on the source collection doesn't do a deep lookup as find.

Answer (score 3):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter` will find entries in the returned array that also match the filter query, and `.find` queries each of those to find children that match the query you entered.

With the markup:

```
<div class="cheese">
    <div class="cheddar"></div>
    <div class="wensleydale"></div>
    <div class="brie">
                <div class="camembert"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This:

```
$('.cheese div').filter('.brie');
```

Would return the brie div, but this:

```
$('.cheese div').filter('.camembert');
```

Would return nothing, when this:

```
$('.cheese div').find('.camembert');
```

Would search deeper, and retrieve the camembert div.

Which is a shame, because Camembert is disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link...  http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/

> Both filter() and find() methods are very similar, except the former
>   is applies to all the elements, while latter searches child elements
>   only.

Answer (score 0):

`find` will search in the decedents for matching elements

`filter` will keep only the matching elements from a set of elements.